# Alternative to goto statement in Java

Tags: java, goto

OK, so I'm sure this question has been beaten to death, but I still can't find the answer I need for my project.

I am working on building a casino game suite in java (I'm 110% sure that there are better, and easier languages for this, but I am learning java right now and I'd like to code in java for the practice.)
My issue is that I cannot figure out how to structure my code. I am used to using goto statements (I started learning coding in small basic). For example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CasinoGames
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
    sopln("Hello, and welcome to Casino Games!");
    sopln("Would you like to login, register, or play as a guest?");
    char token = keys.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    randomlabelhere:
    if (token == "l")
      User.login();
    else if (token == "r")
      User.register();
    else if (token == "g")
      User.guestLogin();
    else
      sopln("Invalid Choice, please try again!");
      goto somerandomlabel
```

I know this won't compile, so please don't mention that. I know that I can use a do-while loop for this, but if I wanted the option to do a goto, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: Don't try to create a Java program using basic logic and structure. Instead learn and use OOP ideas. In sum, let go of your `goto` and move on.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You're thinking of structured programming, not OOP. `goto` has nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: I guess it's about that time :P I was actually planning on using a do-while-loop, but just wanted to know if there was a similar statement ^_^ @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing Java has to a `goto` are labels for `break` and `continue`. Goto has been [considered harmful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful) for longer than Java has been a language, and consequently Java doesn't have a goto implementation (**and** `goto` is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) so you cannot add one). Finally, since `token` is a `char` you should compare with `char` literals like

```
while(true) {
  if (token == 'l')
    User.login();
  else if (token == 'r')
    User.register();
  else if (token == 'g')
    User.guestLogin();
  else {
    sopln("Invalid Choice, please try again!");
    continue;
  }
  break;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `goto` is a reserved word precisely in case they decide to add it one day.

Comment: Yes, but if you use a break, then it skips that labeled block, right? Also, continues can only be used in loops ^_^

Comment: @immibis Actually, Jasmin (the Java assembler) includes a goto (because the JVM has had it since day 1).

Comment: @ElliotFrisch yes, but that's not the Java language, which we're talking about.

Comment: @immibis I know, but it's a bit disingenuous to say *in case they decide to add it one day* when it's already added. Perhaps *in case they decide to enable it one day*, or maybe that should be **unleash**.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch in case they decide to add it *to the language* one day.

Comment: @immibis It is *reserved **in*** the language (along with `const` for some reason).

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Yes? That's exactly what I said.

Answer (score 7):

- A [`for-loop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)
- A [`while-loop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)
- A [`do-while-loop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)
- In fact, just about anything else other the `goto` (IMHO)

Also, `token == "l"` is not how `String` comparison works in Java, you want to something more like `"l".equals(token)`

Besides, `token` is a type of `char` so it should be more like `token == '1'`, but you could get away with using a `String` and using `token.trim().startsWith("1")`, but you'd need to test for a `null` result

Comment: I realized this after I posted this, I actually changed it to: !token=='l', which is char comparison, I believe.

Comment: @AustenClay Not quite; it's `token != 'l'` or `!(token == 'l')`.

Comment: @AustenClay Yes, but your code wouldn't have compiled as `String` and `char` are not compatible.  You can also get away with using `String` and using `startsWith` as your comparison, but that comes down to needs

Comment: @Dev Probably, but lets keep it in the family

Comment: @TNT OK, I knew it was something to that effect, I just wasn't sure of the specifics, I guess it's time to go to the textbook :P

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to, you could take everything that would be under the `goto` and make it it's own method. Say you wanted `goto startInteraction`, then you could do this:

```
void startInteraction(){
    //everything below your "randomlabelhere:" would go in this method
}
```

and then call `startInteraction()` any time you wanted to trigger that.

A difference is that a `goto` wouldn't return to where it was called from, while this method would. That feature could be simulated if you used a `return;` in the line following where you call `startInteraction()` so that the code doesn't continue following the method call.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CasinoGames
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
    sopln("Hello, and welcome to Casino Games!");
    sopln("Would you like to login, register, or play as a guest?");
    while (true) {
      char token = keys.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
      if (token == 'l') {
        User.login();
        break;
      }
      else if (token == 'r') {
        User.register();
        break;
      }
      else if (token == 'g') {
        User.guestLogin();
        break;
      }
      else {
        sopln("Invalid Choice, please try again!");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It will now you've correct the comparison between `char` and `String` ;)

Comment: Heh, that was already in my preview window as I saw your comment, so I didn't see the problem :)

Comment: Well, they aren't defined here because they are separate class files that I have yet to build O.O. Also, I would like to point out that sopln is my psudo-code for System.out.println, which I do a replace all to fix when I'm done ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Casino {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        sopln("Hello, and welcome to Casino Games!");
        sopln("Would you like to login, register, or play as a guest?");
        while (true) {
            char token = input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            if (token == 'l') {
                User.login();
                break;
            } else if (token == 'r') {
                User.register();
                break;
            } else if (token == 'g') {
                User.guestLogin();
                break;
            } else {
                sopln("Invalid Choice, please try again!");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void sopln(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);
}

private static class User {
    static void login() {}

    static void register() {}

    static void guestLogin() {}
}
}
```

Scanner implements AutoCloseable in Java 7+, so I managed it with the try-with-resources feature.

Note: User should be presented with a menu so they know what l, r, and g stand for. I know it seems obvious, but you'd be surprised :-P

I'd also add some sort of escape case for exiting the program.

I'm trying to think of the last time I used a goto statement, and the only thing that comes to mind is MIPS assembly jump operations.